# Glass Augmented Reality Accuracy

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I have a requirement for AR on Glass that I hope you can help me out on. Basically, imagine a book shelf with lots of square book cases lets say 10X10 square book cases for example. So there would be 100 square book cases on the book shelf. Given some parameters, I would need to "highlight" a particular (1) book case out of the 100. Assume the square enclosures are 1 foot X 1 foot.

Would AR using GPS address this use case? I would imagine the square book cases are too small to affect GPS coordinates. Plus the square enclosures are stacked vertically and horizontally.

I have no experience with AR so your inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: GPS resolution is generally measured in metres (except with specialised equipment). You need to look at the image your camera is seeing and use that to overlay your highlights.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve can most certainly be done through augmented reality. However, GPS is not the way to go about this.

GPS is accurate to within +/-20 meters, usually. It is often less, and varies highly on the fix you can get at that location. Your setup is talking of 10x10 feet. 1 meter is approximately 3 feet, so you are going too fine for GPS to help.

In such scenarios, your best bet would be to implement either a single marker on each book case, or a few positional markers in a set, predefined pattern across the book case set up, which can then let you figure out where the user is looking by analysing their position in the frame.

The first solution is trivial and can be implemented easily. The second one will require some level of specific coding and fine tuning, but look better and fancier.

Comment: Hi Raghav, thank you very much for your answer. If I add 1 marker per book case that would not look so good right? Because the user will see several markers possibly 100 in a 10X10 setup. Is my understanding correct? Is it possible to add "invisible" markers that only show up when a certain condition is met? i.e when book case #5 in the first row should be "highlighted" then only that marker is visible? I am planning to use wikitude for the augmented reality sdk. Would you recommend any other please? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3716958 Markers are actual, physical things that the camera can identify, so they definitely cannot be invisible. They can be small, but they must be big enough for the camera to pick up